# How to fetch environment variables in Mac OS X using python?

Tags: python, macos, environment-variables, .profile

How can I lookup environment variables (e.g. export HG_USER from .profile) using python code in Mac OS X?

Comment: What have you tried?  Please post the code you tried and the error you're getting.

Comment: didn't try anything, wanted a direction

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`os.environ` is a dictionary containing all the environment variables. You need to `import os` before you can use it.
So, for example HG_USER would be accessed by `os.environ['HG_USER']`.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `os` module:

```
import os
os.environ
```

Returns a dictionary with the environment variables as keys.

Answer (score 2):

Use `os`:

```
>>> import os
>>> print os.environ["PATH"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also the helper function `os.getenv(varname[, value])` which will return the value of environment variable `varname`, and if it not present will return `value` which defaults to `None`